# Why is this not printing the negative values in my list?

Tags: python

Why is code not printing the negative value in my list? The max value works fine but nothing prints for negative.

```
user_input = ''
user_values = []
x = 0
maxim = 0
sum = 0
avg = 0
neg_values = 0
mini = 0
while True:
    user_input = (input('input:'))
    if user_input in ['q', 'Q']:
        break

    elif user_input not in  ['q', 'Q'] and user_input.isnumeric():
        user_values.append(int(user_input))

for value in user_values:
    maxim = max(value,maxim)
print( "the maximum value in the list is : " , maxim)

Minumum_value = min(user_values)
print( "the minumum value in the list is : " , Minumum_value)

for value in user_values:
    if value < 0:
        print("the negative values are : "  ,  value)
```

The code should work as the user inputs value and quits when he types `q`. Then it should find neg values or the max etc.

Comment: `.isnumeric()` is true for *strings consisting entirely of digits*.  A negative number does not consist entirely of digits...  You really need an `else:` in the input loop, to indicate to the user that they entered something that wasn't accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your `isnumeric` check: that isn't doing what you expect.

```
>>> '-3'.isnumeric()
False
```

The method checks is all characters are digits, the minus sign is not part of it.

You could use a try/except:

```
try:
    user_values.append(int(user_input))
except ValueError:
    print('invalid input')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not doing what you expect because `isnumeric()` doesn't do what you think it does. Try this at a Python prompt:

```
>>> "-1".isnumeric()
False
```

To do what you want, convert the input value to `int` and wrap the conversion in a `try...except ValueError`.

```
try:
    user_values.append(int(user_input))
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input", user_input, "ignored")
```

As a side note, this:

```
for value in user_values:
    maxim = max(value,maxim)
```

is pointless. Instead do `maxim = max(user_values)`. You only need to calculate the maximum once. Same for the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just use try-except?

```
while True:
    user_input = (input('input:'))
    if user_input in ['q', 'Q']:
        break

    elif user_input not in  ['q', 'Q'] and user_input.isnumeric():
        user_values.append(int(user_input))
```

Except Try this code.

```
while True:
    user_input = (input('input:'))
    if user_input in ['q', 'Q']:
        break
    else:
        try:
            user_values.append(int(user_input))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error log...")
```